# Validation in MVC 5 .net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Im try to give alert if there is a error in form in my form there are some text fields validation like below

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xm-12">
            <label class="control-label form-text-align text-top-padding ">
                @Resources.StandardPrice
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xm-12 text-top-padding">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.products.BasicPrice, new { @class = "form-control errorClass", @id = "basicPrice", @placeholder = @Resources.StandardPrice, @onblur = "addClass(this)", @maxlength = Resources.AddNewProductFieldMaxLength })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.products.BasicPrice, null, new { @class = "help-inline" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

if there is some error in form how can I give a alert

Comment: `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` will display the error on the page. Why do you want an alert as well?

Comment: if i submit it will submit

Comment: No it wont (assuming you have correctly implemented client side validation)

Comment: Are you refering to your `@maxlength` attribute? That is HTML-5 validation and does not work with MVC client side validation (using `jquery.validate.js`). Remove it and add a `[StringLength]` attribute to your property

Comment: I think then there is a wrong in client side validation, anyway is there a way to give a alert

Comment: Again, why in the world would you want to do that? If you implement it correctly then the validation message will be displayed and the submit will be cancelled

Comment: that works other validation will give but it will submit with those errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158298/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-hemalherath).

Comment: could you post your class/model and controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already did what @Mohamed Kamel Bouzekria suggested and still not working.
it's possible that you missing something in your controller which could this

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult YOurMethod( Model model)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)//if there is no errors and valid values
            {
               //do something 

                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View();//else return the same view that should display the errors
        }
```

if it still not working then you missing something else in your view.if so post the full code of the view

Comment: im not using a form because there is a mix in js and .net i have use js for an dropdown

Comment: is there a way to get all error message if there is some i can use if not save

Comment: Please post the full view that includes the"mix js and .net" so everyone can get the full picture .of what you want to do.this will also speed up finding the solution .To your question

Answer (score 10):

In order to display the error message and prevent the submission of your form you have to add controls on your model (or ViewModel).

For example if you want that field to be required so that the form will not be submitted only if the user give a value to that field you have to add the [Required] to your product's model attribute "BasicPrice" as follow :

```
public class products {
   public int ID { get; set; }

   [Required]
   public string Name { get; set; }

   [DataType(DataType.Date)]
   public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

   [Required]
   public string Genre { get; set; }

   [Range(1, 100)]
   [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
   public decimal Price { get; set; }

   [StringLength(5)]
   public string Rating { get; set; }
}
```

Here's a link to the Microsoft official Documentation which explain the subject and give more details :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model